# Yammer does not use the latest version of AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, yammer

I am using yammer sample from [this link](https://github.com/yammer/ios-oauth-demo).

After downloading complete code , i found out that I also need to include afnetworking and PDKeychainBindingController libraries. Which i have done successfully.

Problem is the version of the AFNetworking library (which is 1.3 , i guess and not 2.x), I can not use the old version of this library as i have already used the latest version in my complete project. If someone has included the latest afnetworking 2.0 version in the yammer sdk files (in YMHTTPClient.h/.m) , please describe here.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I've updated the Yammer OAuth SDK to AFNetworking 2, [see here](https://github.com/stephsharp/ios-oauth-demo/tree/afnetworking2).

I've also submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/yammer/ios-oauth-demo/pull/2).